# ASP.NET MVC 5 Application calls local WebAPI?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a web application with most of the pages using MVC 5 views except the main page which may use some SPA. However, right now I want to create the main page using MVC 5 view, and rewrite it later using SPA.

Should I create an WebApi controller now; then the controller consume the Web Api controller? So it will make it easier for future?

What's the good way to consume the local WebApi in the another MVC controller? Hope it can be strong typed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a good idea to use Web API as a Rest full service which return JSON data. 
So you can use javascript libraries like Angular or other to call this rest full serivces and use to build your SPA application in future.

If your Web API is in same project you can access a WebAPI controller simply instantiating the class

```
var webApi = new WebAPIController();
var data = webApi.methodName();
```

Or else you can use Jquery ajax and call your web api methods using [Jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Or if its an external web API you can use [HTTPClient](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) to consume Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Here is a a great link and excellent way of doing this.

```
requestMethod.getRequest("POST", "application/json", string.Format("{0}/api/products/", json).GetResponse();
```

Reference:

http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/03/22/accessing-a-asp-net-webapi-rest-service-from-asp-net-mvc/